# How can I change UILabel.text from different swift file?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting nil value error when I try to change UIlabel from a different swift file other than ViewController.

```
//ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    myLabel?.text = "foo"
    }
  func label(stringVal: String? = nil){
      myLabel?.text = stringVal!
    }
}

//Source.swift

//Do working here and get a string value from struct
// I saved that string in stringValue

let VC = MainViewController()
VC.label(stringVal: stringValue!)
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

View controller controls are not created in constructor, it is expected to be null. You need to show that view controller before to run `label` method and avoid the error.

A valid option would be to set an internal variable in the constructor and in `viewDidLoad`, when the label is already created, you could do

```
myLabel.text = stringValue // stringValue is comes from constructor.
```

Comment: can you please be more specific. May be little example will be great. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `MainViewController` @sab3rclaw1225?

Comment: So idea here is keep MainViewController hold all the outlets and do work on outlets in other file i.e. Source.